# Error creating a class object

Tags: c++, class, object

I am having a problem creating a simple class object. I created a small program to simulate the problem. I have a class "Person" with data members `string name`, `string eye_color`, and `int pets`. When I call `Person new_person("Bob", "Blue", 3)`, my debugger shows this as the `new_person`'s value:

`{name=""eye_color=""pets=-858993460}`

I'm looking at previous projects where I had no problems with this and am not spotting anything...What am I missing?

**person.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
    Person(std::string name, std::string eye_color, int pets);
    ~Person();

    std::string name;
    std::string eye_color;
    int pets;
};
```

**person.cpp**

```
#include "person.h"

Person::Person(std::string name, std::string eye_color, int pets)
{
    this->name;
    this->eye_color;
    this->pets;
}
Person::~Person(){}
```

**city.h**

```
#include "person.h"

class City
{
public:
    City();
    ~City();

    void addPerson();
};
```

**city.cpp**

```
#include "city.h"

City::City(){}
City::~City(){}

void City::addPerson(){
    Person new_person("Bob", "Blue", 3);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "city.h"

int main(){
    City myCity;

    myCity.addPerson();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are actually assigning the values in the Person class so that is why you are getting random values for those data members.

It should be:

```
Person::Person(std::string name, std::string eye_color, int pets)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->eye_color = eye_color;
    this->pets = pets;
}
```

Comment: Oops! Not sure how I managed to overlook that after reviewing it a bunch of times. I guess I was initializing the values but not assigning them to anything. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what the exact reason is but in a lot of programming languages you can just write a variable on a single line and it is valid without affecting anything AFAIK.